# Convert CLLocation to MKMapItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have a `CLLocation` for the User's location that I have retrieved from Core Location's locationManager. In order to calculate the distance to a map item, I would like to convert the `CLLocation` into a `MKMapItem`.

I gather you can get the coordinates of the `CLLocation`, make an `MKPlacemark` from them and finally make an `MKMapItem` from the `MKPlacemark` doing something like the following:

```
let currentLocation:CLLocation = locationManager.location
var coord : CLLocationCoordinate2D = currentLocation.coordinate
let myPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coord)
let myMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: myPlacemark)
```

This seems rather lengthy for this task and I am wondering, if there is no more direct way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Could use you [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452002-mapitemforcurrentlocation?language=objc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's the user's current location you're trying to create an MKMapItem of, you can just do this:

```
let myMapItem = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
```

That saves you the trouble of obtaining user's location, too!  :)